# How do make rake run a task automatically with no arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, jasmine

When I run 'rake' with no arguments rspec and cucumber will trigger automatically. I'd like the jasmine:ci task to also run when this happens. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Rakefile you can define custom tasks:

```
task :my_task do           #define custom task
  puts 'my own task"
end

task :default => 'my_task' #set task "my_task" as default task
                           #this task will execute on 'rake' running
```

Comment: Yeah, that works pretty well. If use

"task :default => ['spec', 'jasmine:ci', 'cucumber']" it'll stop on the first task that has a failing test, which is ideal. Thanks!